# C++ code elegance

Tags: c++

Is it considered proper to have code like this:

```
#include <FILEHERE>
using namespace std;

char input;

int main() {
    cin >> input;
    cout << input;

    return 0;
}
```

I know that this code will work, but is is considered proper and is there a better wat to do it?

The reason I am using code similar to this, (but far more complex), is because I have a thread and the main function both using this string at some point, and the only way I could think to declare it for both the thread and main function was to declare it outside the thread and main function. What is a better way to do this?

EDIT: I am not asking about using `namespace std;` as I use it in almost every program I write.

Comment: Indent the code you have in `main()`.

Comment: well, 1.) it's not a string but a single character and 2.) how are they accessing the "string"? Read/write both? One read the other write? Because on multi-core/processor machines you might want to consider some locking primitives then. First I thought you were asking about the global `using namespace std;` actually :)

Comment: Questions of code elegance are off-topic here; they belong on the [code-review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you want to ask how to share variables among multiple threads, then please cut to the chase and *ask that*.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. The thread is writing and the function is reading. And I'm sorry for that I didn't realize my question was ambiguous. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a pointer to a variable local to main thread:

```
int main() { 
  int input;
  set_thread_input(&input);
  /* ... */
  return 0;
}

void thread_func(void *arg){
   int *input = (int*)arg;
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the variable at global scope, yes, that's certainly very common. I think you'll find that more people will object on principle to the `using namespace std` declaration than the object declared at global scope.

Comment: lol, you fell into the same trap as I, I think that wasn't the question even though the question was very ambiguous :)

Comment: Hm, I'm quite neutral about `using`, and I would strongly object to global objects.